# Yii2 shows blank page when render a view with a model

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i'm new working with yii,

maybe is just a estupid thing but a can't make it work,

i have this:

```
$turno = new Turnosservice();
$turno->turno_id = $this->request->get('d');
$turno->disponibilidad_id = $this->request->get('t');
$turno->hash = trim($this->request->get('session'));
$turno->operacion = 'C';
$turno->plataform = $this->getPlatform($this->request->userAgent);
$turno->appversion = $this->request->userAgent;
$turno->appname = $this->getBrowser($this->request->userAgent);
$turno->estado = 0;
$turno->host = $this->request->userIP;

//var_dump($turno);

return $this->render('anulacion', ['model' => $turno]);
```

everything looks good, the model have all the data needed, but when render, just shows a blank page,

but if i do this:

```
return $this->render('anulacion', ['model' => $model = new Turnosservice()]);
```

of course, this last just load a empty model without the data i need.

Comment: what is the name of your action?

Comment: add your view here and are you checking it on local system or live server ?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your answers, i already solved this.

for anyone in the same situation:

the problem was...

i have an Action called:

```
 public function actionIndex()
{... }
```

and inside the action i called a function that process the data. but my mistake was:

the function process (the function that process the data) do:

```
private function process()
{
 .... 
    return $this->render('anulacion', ['model' => $turno]); 
}
```

the problem here is that the Function Action should return the render, not the other function, the action always return the render (if you want to show something)

finally i changed the function action to return the render

```
public function actionIndex
{
  ...
  return $this->render('view', ['model'=>$model]); 
}
```

and that it.

i hope this would be helpfull to others,

PS sorry by my english